# ORA-12505, TNS:listener

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor... I even tried starting the services and it didnt help. Please help and advance thank you.

Comment: So what can be the solution. Do i need to re install the software

Comment: you need to set the variables... try with set `ORACLE_SID=instance_name` and start listener